# How can i implement single sign on with Active Directory in a single page application?

Tags: web, active-directory, single-sign-on, single-page-application

I have a web application and I would like to integrate with a single sign on from Active Directory. After some user login in Windows, the application automatically logs in the user in the application.

I cannot use Internet Explorer for this.

Comment: The answer depends on what framework you're building your web application in, and which OS it will be hosted on, and whether the server is joined to the domain you need to authenticate to.

Comment: I am using angularjs as SPA and the server is windows server.

Comment: Is it hosted in IIS?

Comment: Yes, frontend and backend